CommunityToolkit8.2 IRecipient Some issues in
I encountered a problem while using CommunityToolkit 8.2 IRecipient, which includes IRecipient<Value ChangedMessage<string>>and IRecipient<PropertyChangedMessage<string>>. What are the roles of Value ChangedMessage and PropertyChangedMessage?
Only defining IRecipient<string>as able to receive messages, adding ValueChangedMessage or PropertyChangedMessage will result in incorrect message reception.
I still haven't figured it out, please help me interpret it. thanks!
public partial class TestViewModel: ObservableRecipient, IRecipient<PropertyChangedMessage<string>>
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string info = "message";

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        IsActive = true;
    }

    public void Receive(PropertyChangedMessage<string> message)
    {
        Info = message.NewValue;
    }

}

The above is the code I tested, but it is defined that IRecipientcan receive messages. Of course, after defining IRecipient, the Receive method will also change.
